# Finding a certain users status in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Okay so I am trying to make a discord bot that detects when a certain user is online in my server. But every time I try to get the users presence status it always says "const usersStatus = user.presence.status; TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')". How do I get the presence status of a specific user? Here's my code so far

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token} = require('./config.json');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES] });

const user = client.users.fetch('Users ID');
const usersStatus = user.presence.status;

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log("should be online");
    console.log(usersStatus);
})

//place at end of file
client.login(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Discord, offline members don't have any presence, so the `presence` is null, hence you get the error.

So if presence is null, either the User defined isn't a user or they are offline.

Secondly, you will need to resolve the promise by adding `await`

Usually, I would do this to get to know their status.

```js
let user = await client.users.fetch("ID")
console.log(`${user.tag}'s presence status: ${user.presence?.status ?? "offline"}`)
```

This will log for example: `Ashish#0540's presence status: dnd` if the person is on do not disturb, or `Ashish#0540's presence status: offline`

Comment: Well it's running at least, but now it's giving me "undefined's presence status: offline" instead of your output. Even when I give it the ID of someone who is currently online it still gives me the exact same thing.

Comment: You will need to await the promise, i forgot to do that.

Comment: I tried it and it at least prints out the tag but it still prints offline even if the user is online

Answer (score 0):

[`client.users.fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=fetch) returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). You will need to await it and get the presence from there

```js
(async () => { //await needs async
const user = await client.users.fetch('Users ID');
const usersStatus = user.presence.status
})()
```

Additionally, you won't get any users if the client is not ready. You should make sure this is in your `ready` event so the client fetches the user properly.

In discord.js v13 [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User)s don't have `presence`s. This is only on [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)s now. I believe this is for security reasons - like bots can only DM members they are in a guild with. You can get any guild that this user is in, then get the member from there where you will then get their status

```js
const member = await guild.members.fetch('Users ID'); //remember you still need async
const membersStatus = member.presence.status
```

Comment: I keep getting an error saying that status doesn't exist. And just doing "await guild.members.fetch('Users ID');" doesn't work either. Any suggestions?

Comment: A GuildMember's presence can be `null`.